# IOException with HTTP response code: 400 occurs intermittently and works after server restart

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400

Basically I am invoking a REST service which transfers a packet of small data from my system to the other. This works fine at the beginning but after some time if I leave it as such for a week and try to invoke the same service I am getting the below error

> IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400.

The issue is resolved once I restart the webserver

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

I tried all below suggestions

```
con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
```

I also made the connection object to null and allow connection object for Garbage collection

but none of this solved the issue.

Comment: The same request when I hit with SOAP UI, I get a success response. Post restart the same request gives success response from the above code itself. So there is no chance with the error in the input request.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without information about the server. Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The IOException on the client means, that the server sended a response with the HTTP Response code 400.

This Response code indicates an error(Bad Request) and because of this, the client tells you (with the IOException) that there is something wrong with the response.

Most likely, the server did not expect the request you sent.
For example, you could have special characters in the URL or did not include cookies.

If you want to read the content of the response, you can use `con.getErrorStream();`

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions right now solved my issue. But yet to wait for sometime to see since the issue in intermittent and doesnt comes everytime

1. JVM  cache clearance from java security file
2. Change the implementation with spring boot rest template.